# Regex for matching indented continuation lines

Tags: regex, perl

Need match `key = value` pairs in arbitrary text using the following rules.

- the leading line has a structure:

  - start with indentation - "two spaces or tab" at leas once, e.g.: `(  |\t)+`
  - the `+` character and one space
  - words `VAR` or `CONST`
  - and the `key` and `value` using the `=` character

Examples:

```
  + VAR somename = somevalue (indented with two spaces)
        + VAR name3 = indented by one \t
```

The following regex matches such lines:

```
/^(  |\t)+\+\s+(VAR|CONST)\s+(\w+)\s*=\s*(.*)$/
```

Now the problem: The syntax allows **continuation lines**, e.g. when the above line is followed by the line which starts at least one indentation sequence `(  |\t)` (aka TWO spaces or one tab) is considered as an continuation line and its whole content (with leading spaces too) should be the `value` for the key in previous line.

Example:

```
  + VAR multi = 3 line value where the continuation lines
  are indented (starts with two spaces or one tab)
  and NOT followed by the '+'
```

e.g., the regex for the *continuation line* is

```
/^(  |\t)+([^\+](.*))$/
```

The solution is easy with *line based* approach, e.g. when I split the whole text into lines and processes it line-by-line.

But, I looking for an (complex) regex (mainly for learning and benchmarking purposes) which could match the key=value pairs in one line or multiline form. Tried this:

```
while( $text =~ m/^(  |\t)+\+\s+(VAR|CONST)\s+(\w+)\s*=\s*((.*)$(?=(  |\t)+[^\+](.*)$)*)/gm ) {
    ...
}
```

but I got:

```
(?=(  |\t)+[^\+](.*)$)* matches null string many times in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^(  |\t)+\+\s+(VAR|CONST)\s+(\w+)\s*=\s*((.*)$(?=(  |\t)+[^\+](.*)$)* <-- HERE )/ at so line 36.
```

**Side question:** how to use the multi-line extended regexes, like:

```
/
   ^(  |\t)+      # <- space ... :(
   \+\s+
   (VAR|CONST)
   \s+
   (\w+)
   \s*=\s*
   (.*)$
/x
```

when the regex must contain exactly the SPACE character (e.g. can't use the universal `\s`)?

If someone want help, here is a code which produces the wanted output (using the line-based approach) and also the non-working `regex-based` solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $txt = do { local $/; <DATA> };

my @matches1 = parse_by_lines($txt // '');
mydump('BY LINES', @matches1);

my @matches2 = parse_by_one_regex($txt // '');
mydump('REGEX', @matches2);

sub parse_by_lines { #produces the wanted output
    my ($text) = @_;
    my @match;
    my $havekey;
    for my $line (split "\n", $text) {
        if( $line =~ m/^(  |\t)+\+\s+(VAR|CONST)\s+(\w+)\s*=\s*(.*)$/ ) {
            push @match, { indent => $1, type => $2, key => $3, val => $4 };
            $havekey++;
        }
        elsif( $havekey && $line =~ m/^(  |\t)+([^\+](.*))$/ ) {    #continuation line
            $match[-1]->{val} .= "\n$line"; #prserve the \n in the val
        }
        else {
            $havekey = 0;
        }
    }
    return @match;
}


sub parse_by_one_regex { #not working
    my ($text) = @_;
    my @match;
    while( $text =~ m/^(  |\t)+\+\s+(VAR|CONST)\s+(\w+)\s*=\s*((.*)$(?=(  |\t)+[^\+](.*)$)*)/gm ) {
        push @match, { indent => $1, type => $2, key => $3, val => $4 };
    }
    return @match;
}

sub mydump {
    my($label, @match) = @_;
    say "#### $label ####";
    for my $m ( @match ) {
        printf "%-6s: [%s]\n", $_, $m->{$_} for (qw(indent type key val));
        print "\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
some arbitrary text lines
or empty lines

    could be indented
  and could contain any character

  + VAR name1 = var indented by two spaces and the first nonspace character is '+'
line of arbitrary text
    + VAR name2 = var indented by 2x2 spaces

    + VAR name3 = var indented by one \t
  + VAR name4 = the next line with "name5" is not valid. missing the = character, should not be matched
  + VAR name5
  + CONST name6 = the type could be VAR or CONST

  + VAR multi1 = multiline value where the continuation lines
  are indented (starts with two spaces or one tab) and NOT followed by the '+'

  + VAR multi1 = multiline value
    indented

  + VAR multi1 = multiline value
     indented ok too


  + VAR single = this is single line
  + because this line even if it is indented, the first nonspace character is '+'

  + VAR multi2 = multiline
  could be
     indented
        any way
  and any number of times
  until the first non-indented line

the following should NOT match

+ VAR some = sould not be matched, because the line isn't indented
 + VAR some = sould not be matched, because the line isn't indented at least with TWO spaces or one tab
  + SOME name = value not matched because the SOME isn't VAR or CONST
```

---

**EDIT:** using the accepted answer, and adding the wanted capture groups, got the following:

```
    while( $text =~ /
            (?m)            # multiline match
            ^               # at the start of the line
            ([ ]{2}|\t)+    # two spaces or tab - at least once
            \+              # the '+' character
            \s*             # followed by any number of spaces (e.g. "+VAR" or "+    VAR" are valid)
            (VAR|CONST)     # the VAR or CONST
            \s+             # followed at least one space (e.g. the "VAR_" should not matched)
            (\w+)           # the keyword
            \s*=\s*         # the '=' surrounded (and consumed) by any number of spaces
            (               # capture the whole value (as it is)
                    .*                      # any string up to end of line
                    (?:                     # followed by (non-capturing group)
                            \R              # one line-break
                            ^               # at the start of the line
                            (?>[ ]{2,}|\t+) # atomic group - at least two spaces or at least one tab
                            [^+]            # followed by any character but '+'
                            .*              # any string up the end of line
                    )*              # any number of times (e.g. optionally)
            )
    /xg) {
            push @match, { indent => $1, type => $2, key => $3, val => $4 };
    }
```

---

**EDIT2** And yes, the regex based solution is 34% faster (at least on my HW).

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that.

Comment: Your tries *hints* that you want to **capture** the `key` and `value`, but your question says **match**. Which is it? If it's the latter, I believe revo has given you the answer below. If you want to capture it, it's more complicated...

Comment: Ahh... Now I see that you've accepted. There's the answer to my Q. :)

Comment: @ClasG heh, you're right. Added an edit for my final solution, using the accepted answer. :)

Comment: Your edited solution misses the commencing `+`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regex:

```
(?m)^(?:  +|\t+)\+ *(?:VAR|CONST) *\w+ *=.*(?:\R^(?>  +|\t+)[^+\s].*)*
```

[**Live demo**](https://regex101.com/r/iA3kU7/9)

The important part is last cluster:

```
(?:                # Start of non-capturing group (a)
    \R             # One line-break
    ^              # Start of line
    (?>  +|\t+)    # At least two spaces or one tab character (possessively)
    [^+\s]         # Not followed by `+` or a newline character
    .*             # Up to end of line
)*                 # Repeat it as much as possible - end of non-capturing group (a)
```

**Answer to your second question**:

Literal space characters are simply ignored as a meaningful part of Regular Expression while `x` modifier is set unless you enclose it in character classes `[ ]` and use quantifiers `[ ]{2,}` to express times they should appear.

```
/
    (?m)
    ^
    (?:
        [ ]{2,}
        |
        \t+
    )\+
    [ ]*
    (?:
        VAR
        |
        CONST
    )
    [ ]*\w+[ ]*=.*
    (?:
        \R
        ^
        (?>
            [ ]{2,}
            |
            \t+
        )
        [^+\s].*
    )*
/x
```

**[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/iA3kU7/8)**

Comment: Thanks for the live demo links, cool site!

Your first regex mostly works, but if the line `line of arbitrary text` is deleted it needs a small fix: replace `[^+]` with `(?!\s*\+)`

Comment: Thank you for noting. I changed non-capturing group to an atomic group to prevent any possible backtracks. @KjetilS.

Comment: Please check update. I made some improvements. @cajwine

Comment: Just found the problem and returned here to ask additional info, but the solution is already corrected. I love the stackoverflow community. Thanx again.